# Extract integer from string using bash

Tags: string, bash, integer

I tried to find the solution here but could not; given strings like

```
ABC3
DFGSS34
CVBB3
```

how do I extract the integers so I get

```
3
34
3
```

??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just a simple sed command will do the job:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' file.txt
```

#### OUTPUT

```
3
34
3
```

Comment: What is the case for fractional number eg: 123.43 ?

Comment: Since question was extracting integer so this was answer for that. For floating point a different solution is needed.

Comment: It is not appropriate to answer a new question from comment section. If you post a question then I will surely try to answer.

Answer (score 13):

For a bash-only solution, you can use parameter patter substition:

```
pax$ xyz=ABC3 ; echo ${xyz//[A-Z]/}
3
pax$ xyz=DFGSS34 ; echo ${xyz//[A-Z]/}
34
pax$ xyz=CVBB3 ; echo ${xyz//[A-Z]/}
3
```

It's very similar to `sed` solutions but has the advantage of not having to fork another process. That's probably not important for small jobs but I've had situations where this sort of thing was done to many, many lines of a file and the non-forking is a significant speed boost.

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration there might be other non-alphanumeric characters in the given string, such as `()[]{}#$!.` etc. Shouldn't it better read `echo ${xyz//[^0-9]/}` instead for extracting "nothing but integers"?

Answer (score 8):

How about using `tr`?

```
for s in ABC3 DFGSS34 CVBB3 ; do
    tr -cd 0-9 <<<"$s"
    echo
done
```

Answer (score 7):

What about a `grep` version?

```
grep -o '[0-9]*' file.txt
```

Comment: grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*' file.txt

Comment: @Mahdi: For *this* particular use case that's not necessary. But in general you are right.

Comment: why not grep -o "[0-9]\+" instead of grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*'