# How to extract a numeric value from a alphanumeric filename

Tags: shell

How to extract a numeric value from a alphanumeric filename using shell script.

Eg. ABC1234A

Here I need to extract the numbers 1234 for comparing it with a value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract integer from string using bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388046/extract-integer-from-string-using-bash)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ file=ABC1234A
$ file=$(echo "$file" | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
$ echo "$file"
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every `grep` has the option `o`. Here's a version without `grep`:

```
$ n=`echo ABC1234A|sed s/\[^0-9]//g`; echo $n
```