# evaluate program output as an integer in bash

Tags: bash

I have an application which outputs a string with a number, like this:

```
output number is 20.
```

I have a code which parses output and cutting out only the number:

```
result=$(./my_script | awk 'print $4')
echo $result
```

the result output will be "20" as expected, but now, if I would try to use it as an integer, for example:

```
result=$((result+1))
```

then I will get an error:

```
13915: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "20")
```

Using it as a seq argument will also give an error

```
$(seq 0 $result) 
seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘\033[?25h\033[?0c20’
```

trying to print it with %q will give the same result:

```
printf '%q' $result
'\E[?25h\E[?0c20'
```

So, it looks like there are some unexpected characters in the string, but I'm not sure how to trim them?

Thank you!

Comment: The application has written ANSI escapes like "Make cursor visible" even though stdout is not a terminal. This is not canonical Unix behavior, and the application shouldn't be doing it. It's not supposed to be your responsibility to trim it. Which application is this?

Comment: Specifically, well-behaved programs will look at whether output is a TTY, and only put escape sequences in place if that check returns true (if the program is implemented in shell, this is accomplished with `[ -t 1 ]` for stdout, `[ -t 2 ]` for stderr; in C, the call is `isatty()`). This program is buggy, and you should report those bugs to its author.

Comment: @thatotherguy Actually, i run that script on other machine using:ssh user@host <<'ENDSSH';
    result=$(./my_script | awk 'print $4');
    echo $result;
ENDSSH;
Unfortunately, I can't make new lines in comment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As I mention in my previous comment - I run it in nested ssh session and try to capture all output, so, probably, I'm getting some garbage too.

Comment: @Tutankhamen, unless you ran with `ssh -tt` to force an emulated TTY when output isn't going to a real one, a program that puts escape sequences in stdout is still incorrect on the part of the program generating it.

Comment: @Tutankhamen, the other thing is that in a command substitution -- `foo=$(bar)` -- stdout isn't going to the SSH session at all, but to a FIFO that's read to collect the output from `bar`, so the use of SSH is irrelevant; if `bar` checks whether its stdout is a tty, it will get false, because its stdout is to a FIFO.

Comment: Consider `ssh -T` to explicitly *disable* TTY emulation on SSH's part. BTW, `echo $result` introduces some bugs in and of itself, like replacing a `*` in the output with a list of files. Better to use `echo "$result"`, or -- to remove everything but numbers -- `echo "${result//[^[:digit:]]/}"`... or just to avoid the command substitution altogether and let the pipeline write direct to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to get the number by using [Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388071/3286975).

It worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(bash output.sh | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
r=$((result+1))
echo $r
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When dealing with a single line, `sed` (or any other external tool) is much higher overhead than bash's built-in string manipulation; for example, `result=${result//[^[:digit:]]/}`

Answer (score 0):

Or, simply, change the field separator

```
result=$(./my_script | awk -F '[. ]' '{print $4}')
echo $result
```